# Why is this episode of Legends of Tomorrow named as such?

Tags: title, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

Season 4 Episode 9 of DC's Legends of Tomorrow is named as **Lucha de Apuestas**. What is the reason behind naming it as such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a fan of the show but I am a native Spanish speaker so I will say that "Lucha" means wrestling.  There are many famous luchadores from Mexico such as El Santo, Blue Demon and Nacho Libre (kidding but his character was based on a real-life person)

"Apuesta" is a bet, so betting and wrestling are concepts referenced therein

So, back to the episode, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legends_of_Tomorrow_(season_4)#Episodes)

> Meanwhile, the rest of the Legends find Konane in 1961 Mexico City as a professional wrestler named "El Lobo", having overshadowed another wrestler named "El Cura". In order to preserve the timeline, they plan to have El Lobo lose to El Cura in a Lucha de Apuestas. Sara confronts Ava about Nate and Zari's suspicions, but she does not believe her and has her team go after Konane. In 1961, El Cura reclaims his old glory by helping the Legends stop the Time Bureau from capturing Konane.

There is also a term I had forgotten about but a link on that wiki led me to the definition of ["lucha de apuesta"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucha_libre#Luchas_de_Apuestas)

> With the importance placed on masks in lucha libre, losing the mask to an opponent is seen as the ultimate insult, and can at times seriously hurt the career of the unmasked wrestler. Putting one's mask on the line against a hated opponent is a tradition in lucha libre as a means to settle a heated feud between two or more wrestlers. In these battles, called luchas de apuestas ("matches with wagers"), the wrestlers "wager" either their mask or their hair

Comment: thanks I am not a native Spanish speaker so I did not get the meaning before now its clear to me